# How to get latitude without North South in R

Tags: r

So I have a file with something like `Lat 12N Lon 2W` and was wondering how to get it to just be `Lat 12 Lon 2`.

The problem is there is also East so I would have to make it negative but I have no idea.

at$Lat <- sub("N,","",at$Lat)

That just gets rid of North and the "," but I need to make the entries negative for where its East.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

I think a [*lookbehind*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) regex fits well here:

```r
s <- "Lat 12N Lon 2W"
gsub("(?<=\\d)[NESW]", "", s, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "Lat 12 Lon 2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you:

```
x <- c("12N","2W","2E","2S","6W"); x
[1] "12N" "2W"  "2E"  "2S"  "6W" 

x1 <- sub("[NW]","",x); x1
[1] "12" "2"  "2E" "2S" "6" 

x2 <- sub("(\\d)[SE]$","-\\1", x1); x2
[1] "12" "2"  "-2" "-2" "6"
```

Edit:

```
x <- c("Lat 12N Lon 2W", "Lat 13S Lon 2E", "Lat 14N Lon 3W", "Lat 15N Lon 3E"); x
[1] "Lat 12N Lon 2W" "Lat 13S Lon 2E" "Lat 14N Lon 3W" "Lat 15N Lon 3E"

x1 <- gsub("[NW]","",x); x1  # Remove NW
[1] "Lat 12 Lon 2"   "Lat 13S Lon 2E" "Lat 14 Lon 3"   "Lat 15 Lon 3E"

x2 <- sub("(Lat )(\\d+)S","\\1-\\2", x1); x2 # Add "-" in front for Lat S
[1] "Lat 12 Lon 2"   "Lat -13 Lon 2E" "Lat 14 Lon 3"   "Lat 15 Lon 3E"

x3 <- sub("(Lon )(\\d+)E","\\1-\\2", x2); x3 # Add "-" in front for Lon E
[1] "Lat 12 Lon 2"   "Lat -13 Lon -2" "Lat 14 Lon 3"   "Lat 15 Lon -3"
```